# c++: truth assignment warning with arguments?

Tags: c++, arguments, compiler-warnings

I use the following to work with arguments in my programs, but it seems to just hand me a warning (just a warning): `"warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"`

The beginning of the code is as follows:

```
   while((++argv)[0] && argv[0][0]=='-'){
      while(c =* ++argv[0])
```

The `while(c =* ++argv[0])` part being where the warning persists. The code works fine, but what does this warning mean opposed to what is used?

I think the code is `c = *++argv[0]`, using the pointer. So why does the single `=` work and what is really recommended to be used?

Comment: c =* ((++argv)[0]), if thats what you want to do..

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is unsure whether you intended

```
while(c == whatever)
```

instead. It's a common error to *misuse* assignment instead of comparison inside the conditional expression. Sometimes you do want assignment, sometimes not and the compiler gives a warning. To make the compiler see that you really want assignment and not emit the warning use:

```
while((c =* ++argv[0]) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to double the parenthesis to explicitly state that you really mean to test the value of c:

```
while( (c =* ++argv[0]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler warns because you might accidently have written a statement instead of an expression. By embedding the statement in parentheses you tell the compiler your intention and stop him warning.